# Where to define long message strings with parameters

Tags: ios, string

I would like to display some longer messages (>100 characters) with parameters in my iOS application. They would appear in different parts of the application, and would contain information about the state of some processes e.g.

```
[_labelProgressInformation setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ is busy.",currentProcess.Name]];
[_labelUserInformation setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please wait for %@ to finish. Make sure that... blah blah blah with instructions",currentProcess.Name]];
```

The question is where should i define them? I would like to avoid hard coding them in many places. Ideally I'd like to have them in one file, so that I can edit them quickly if it would be necessary. How should i go about this? What is the proper way of defining messages that require parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach to this, also regarding potential multi-language use of your application, would be to use *localized* `.strings` files. That way, you can just refer to the corresponding string value using a key and the predefined Xcode macro `NSLocalizedString(<key>, <comment>)` that takes the *key* as an `NSString` and an optional *comment* for this particular string.

Note that this approach also pays off if you only provide your app in *one* language, it is generally considered **best practice**.

An example use of this would look like this:

You have a localization file:
`Localizable.strings`(English) with an entry:

```
"hello" = "Hello";
"hello_my_name_is" = "Hello, my name is %@";
```

Then, in your application wherever you want to use that string you can do something like this following:

```
helloLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"hello", nil); // will write "Hello"
nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"hello_my_name_is", nil), @"John"]; // will write "Hello, my name is John"
```

You can read more about localization [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Introduction/Introduction.html) or follow [this great tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014).

Answer (score 1):

For this, go for Macros
Just create new header file (NewFile -> Source -> Header File)

define the Macros like

```
#define PROGESSTEXT(text) ([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ is busy.",text])
```

then use it where required like

```
PROGESSTEXT(@"Helloooooo")

    NSLog(@"%@",PROGESSTEXT(@"Helloooooo"));
```

Result : Helloooooo is busy.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I think that nburk's method is a bit better.